# Slow Web Project in vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, performance

i have a problem regarding vs 2008, that it is very very very slow, hangs, even if i type "=" building process is not that bad but lagging too much while programing
my system specs are

4gb ram
2.0 c2d
1 gb grahpic card
vista 64

Can somebody tell me solution for this

i have installed visual assist and i have also tried to disable it but the problem still occurs, any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the problem when I tried working under Vista as well.  It turned out to be traceable to a problem with an out-of-date version of ReSharper.  Ultimately I abandoned ReSharper for other reasons (mostly the move to VS 2010).  In addition, I also experienced a significant improvement in performance when I moved to Windows 7 (64-bit professional). Just a thought, your results may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I [recently](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2010/01/massive-suo-file-causes-visual-studio.html) had a problem with Visual Studio 2008 being extremely slow (Windows 7 64-bit, 4gb ram, quad core processor), particularly when there were build errors or when loading/saving the solution.

The problem ended up being that the `suo` file for the solution (in the same directory as the solution) had become corrupted and was 250mb. After deleting it and reloading the solution, the file was 250kb and the project was fast again.

If this is indeed the cause of your problem, I recommend making a backup of the corrupt suo file before deleting it, as I'm sure Microsoft would like to see it (log a bug at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/)) - I deleted mine without thinking.